# GitHub keeps asking for username/password; BitBucket does not

Tags: git, github, ssh

For a while now I have been using BitBucket in Git bash (Mysysgit for Windows). Recently I've added GitHub, but while git stores my BitBucket credentials, it does not for GitHub.

I've tried various things and approaches (amongst [this tutorial](http://blog.glassdiary.com/post/64098582755/setting-up-ssh-for-github-and-bitbucket) and various SO questions).

Here's what I've done in detail:

**1)** Create key pairs for GitHub.

**2)** Uploaded the public key to the `SSH keys` in the GitHub account settings.

**3)** Tested both key pairs:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/***/.ssh/id_rsa_github':
Hi ***! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

$ ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
logged in as ***.
You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
```

**4)** Updated my config file with the following:

```
Host bitbucket.*
 User ***
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host github.*
 HostName github.com
 User ***
 ForwardAgent yes
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github
```

**5)** Added the private key and passphrase:

```
$ eval `ssh-agent`
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github
Enter passphrase for /c/Users/***/.ssh/id_rsa_github:
Identity added: /c/Users/***/.ssh/id_rsa_github (/c/Users/***/.ssh/id_rsa_github)
$ ssh-add -L
ssh-rsa **key here*** /c/Users/***/.ssh/id_rsa_github
```

**6)** Added a `.bashrc` file to autostart the ssh-agent:

```
eval `ssh-agent`
```

And still:

```
$ git push origin master
Username for 'https://github.com':
```

Where am I going wrong?

---

*Edit:* After following the suggestion to switch to SSH, git does not ask my password/username every time. However, now it asks every time for my passphrase. From one git session:

```
$ git push origin master
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/***/.ssh/id_rsa_github':
Counting objects: 5, done.
***

$ git commit -am "Minor edit"
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

$ git push origin master
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/***/.ssh/id_rsa_github':
```

I've updated my `.bashrc` file as Github [suggests it](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases), but as I understand it, it should only ask once for my passphrase. Even if I run mysysgit with administrator privileges, the passphrase is not saved.

Comment: You are using a https repo url, I.e. you aren't using ssh at all.

Comment: Thanks @AD7six, after switching to SSH it does not ask me for my username/password any more. However, now it keeps asking me for my passphrase every time (after adding the Github key with `ssh-add`, and even after manually starting ssh-agent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the problem by doing the following:

1) Used GitHub's suggestion for `.bashrc` found [here](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases#platform-windows) (thanks @poke);

2) Changed the `.bashrc` code to add the location to my keys:

```
...
if ! agent_is_running; then
    agent_start
    ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github
elif ! agent_has_keys; then
    ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github
fi
...
```

3) Updated my `config` file in accordance to BitBucket's documentation [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=271943168#ConfiguremultipleSSHidentitiesforGitBash,MacOSX,&Linux-CreateaSSHconfigfile) to:

```
# Bitbucket account
Host bitbucket.org
 HostName bitbucket.org
 PreferredAuthentications publickey
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

# GitHub account
Host github.com
 HostName github.com
 PreferredAuthentications publickey
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github
```

4) And, this step was missing from my previous attempts, use the bash command `ps` to list all processes, and then `kill` **any** instance of `ssh-agent` (so that there was no `ssh-agent` running anymore).

5) Then I restarted git bash, and was immediately prompted for the Github passphrase on start-up. This time, however, it was remembered by the ssh-agent.

Previously I also verified that there were no multiple instances of `ssh-agent`, but I did not kill every instance of `ssh-agent`, since that was counter-intuitive. However, in order for the `.bashrc` file to work correctly, this was apparently needed.

Hopefully these steps might also be helpful for others with a similar problem.

Answer (score 3):

GitHub offers multiple ways to access repositories. The current default is via `https` URLs which do not use your SSH information. The URLs look like this:

```
https://github.com/<owner>/<project>.git
git@github.com:<owner>/<project>.git
```

Just switch to the second kind, the SSH address, and Git will use your SSH information.

Comment: Thanks Poke for your answer and explanation: it does not ask for my password and username any more. However, now it keeps asking for my passphrase (I've updated my question). Do you might have an idea?

Comment: See [this guide](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-ssh-key-passphrases#platform-windows) on how to set up ssh-agent correctly.